# Product of square matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

I have a square, symmetric and positive definite $n \times n$ matrix $X$. Given two $n \times n$ square matrices, $A$ and $B$, I would like to understand if there are sufficient conditions, other than $A = B$, that guarantee that the product

$Y = AXB'$

is still a square, symmetric and positive definite matrix. This would help me define a model for $Y$ in a regression model for matrices.

Comment: IMHO you formulated your question in a very (too) sparse manner, e.g., lacking the motivation. Thus enriching via editing would be greatly appreciated by the community & helps in answering.
At the time of writing there is 1 Vote for closure saying "Missing context or other details".
That the product of two positive (semi-)definite matrices is positive (semi-)definite iff the matrices commute may be a helpful fact when revising your post.

Answer (score 0):

There are more general ways of producing psd's from a psd. For instance, one could consider maps

$$X \mapsto \sum_k A_k\cdot X \cdot A_k^{t}$$
for some $(A_k)_k$

There are other linear maps, the term is "positive linear map"